# \graphicspath not working with subfiles

Tags: graphics, subfiles

I'm writing a document organized in many parts, so I use the subfiles packages.

Each subdocuments has a directory for it's images :

```
./img/
./img/1-Intro/test.png
./img/2-Analysis/
```

So my code ressemble to that :

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{report}
  ...
  \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{
      {./img/}
      {./img/1-Intro/}
      {./img/2-Analysis/}      
    }
  \usepackage{subfiles}
  \begin{document}
    \subfile{subfile1.tex}
  \end{document}
```

And my subfile :

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
  \begin{document}
    ...
    \includegraphics{test}
    ...    
  \end{document}
```

When I compile the main file it works as excepted but when I compile the subfile the image is not found.

So I tried to copy the `\graphicspath` both into the main and subfiles but in this case the subfile find the image but not the main.

Does any of you guys know how to fix it ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Copy the graphicspath{...} code from the main.tex into the subfile.tex, it would work!

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Apply the command `\subfix` to the path in your subfiles, like `\graphicspath{{\subfix{./img/}}}`. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the behaviour is still the same :(

Comment: Is your installation up-to-date? I can compile your mwe without problem.

Comment: this did not work for me.